# jQuery can not find dynamically inserted Ionic Framework element

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a plugin that needs to find an element that is inserted into a Cordova page (with Ionic Framework). I am running into trouble when I need to have jQuery manipulate some elements that are inserted by the Ionic Framework.

All works well when I try to operate on non-dynamic elements so I know that the manipulations are working correctly.

The problem I am getting is that the jQuery selector is no finding the element and returning undefined. How can I ask jQuery to look again after I am sure the element exists?

Code:

```
<ion-view has-footer="true" title="">
    <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
        <button menu-toggle="right" class="button button-icon icon-right"><i class="ion-gear-a menu-icon"></i></button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
    <ion-content class="has-header sb-bg">
        <div id="items">
            <!-- First special s -->
            <ion-item ng-repeat="s in ss | limitTo:1" ng-class="{first_s: $first }">
                <div class="s-controls">
                    <button ng-click="show_share()"
                            class="button button-icon s-share-button"><i class="ion-forward s-share-icon"></i>
                    </button>
                    <div class="countdownexample" data-timer="20"></div>
                    <button ng-click="playPause($event, s.audio_file_url)"
                            class="button button-icon s-play-button"><i class="ion-play s-play-icon"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="s-info">
                    <h1>{{ s.market_code }}</h1>

                    <p>{{ s.headline }}</p>
                    <h4 class="tos">{{ timeformat(s.created_at) }}</h4>
                </div>
            </ion-item>

            <button class="btn btn-success start">Start</button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger stop">Stop</button>
            <button class="btn btn-info restart">Restart</button>
            <script>
                $(".countdownexample").TimeCircles({   // is undefined when trying to operate on this
                    start: true,
                    direction: "Counter-Clockwise",
                    count_past_zero: false,
                    fg_width: 0.1,
                    use_background: false,
                    total_duration: 20,
                    time: {
                        Days: {show: false},
                        Hours: {show: false},
                        Minutes: {show: false},
                        Seconds: {color: '#FF0000', text: null}
                    }
                });

                $(".start").click(function () {
                    $(".countdownExample").TimeCircles().start();
                });
                $(".stop").click(function () {
                    $(".countdownExample").TimeCircles().stop();
                });
                $(".restart").click(function () {
                    $(".countdownExample").TimeCircles().restart();
                });
            </script>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: jQuery's `$()` (`jQuery()`) function **never** returns `undefined`. If you have a plugin that is failing with an empty jQuery set, that plugin has a bug in it that should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that as of when you do:

```
$(".countdownexample").TimeCircles(/*...*/);
```

...there are no elements that match `.countdownexample`. You need to hook into whatever event the ionic framework raises when it has done its job and execute that code *then*, when the elements exist. (Perhaps you need to wait for ionic's [`ready` callback](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/utility/ionic.Platform/#ready), although the documentation suggests that happens after `window.onload`, which is **very** late in the page load cycle.)